# Google maps geocoder. How to decode the coordinates using Promise in ngOnInit. Angular CLI

Tags: angular, google-maps, promise

I have the following method:

```
  getAddress(latitude: number, longitude: number): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
      this.geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, (results: { formatted_address: any; }[], status: string) => {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          resolve(results[1].formatted_address);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Using coordinates I want to get formatted address. And I have array event:

```
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  formattedString: string;
```

attributes lat and lng are pre-filled. And I need to calculate formattedString and display this on the html page.

I'm trying do it something like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllEvents();
    this.events?.forEach(async event => event.formattedString = await this.getAddress(59.673858, 70.815982).then(addr => addr));
  }
```

getAllEvents - gets all events with coordinates. And after getting all events, I want to fill for each element formattedString. But my solution doesn't work. To return value from Promise I should use await. If I use await, hence one should use async and as result I get Promise again..

Can anybody help me out ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllEvents().add(() => {
      this.events.map(x => this.mapService.getAddress(x.location.lng, x.location.lat)
        .then(address => x.formattedAddres = address));
    })
  }
```